# Finding Bullish and Bearish Pinbar Candlestick pattern

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to find candles matching to the Pinbar pattern and in order to do that I'm using the built-in implementation for Inverted Hammer - Bullish. How do I locate the opposite of it - Inverted Hammer - Bearish?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Inverted Hammer", overlay = true)

isInvertedHammer() =>
    len = 14 // ta.ema depth for bodyAvg
    shadowPercent = 5.0 // size of shadows
    shadowEqualsPercent = 100.0
    dojiBodyPercent = 5.0
    factor = 2.0 // shows the number of times the shadow dominates the candlestick body
    
    bodyHi = math.max(close, open)
    bodyLo = math.min(close, open)
    body = bodyHi - bodyLo
    bodyAvg = ta.ema(body, len)
    smallBody = body < bodyAvg
    longBody = body > bodyAvg
    upShadow = high - bodyHi
    dnShadow = bodyLo - low
    hasUpShadow = upShadow > shadowPercent / 100 * body
    hasDnShadow = dnShadow > shadowPercent / 100 * body
    whiteBody = open < close
    blackBody = open > close
    rangehl = high - low
    isInsideBar = bodyHi[1] > bodyHi and bodyLo[1] < bodyLo
    bodyMiddle = body / 2 + bodyLo
    shadowEquals = upShadow == dnShadow or (math.abs(upShadow - dnShadow) / dnShadow * 100) < shadowEqualsPercent and (math.abs(dnShadow - upShadow) / upShadow * 100) < shadowEqualsPercent
    isDojiBody = rangehl > 0 and body <= rangehl * dojiBodyPercent / 100
    doji = isDojiBody and shadowEquals
    
    isInvertedHammerBullish = smallBody and body > 0 and bodyHi < hl2 and upShadow >= factor * body and not hasDnShadow
    
    isInvertedHammerBullish

plotshape(isInvertedHammer(), title = "Inverted Hammer", style = shape.labeldown, location = location.abovebar, color = color.new(color.blue, 30), text = "IH", textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bearish verison of the inverted hammer is called "[shooting star](https://www.babypips.com/learn/forex/lone-rangers-single-candlestick-patterns)".

> The Inverted Hammer and Shooting Star also look identical. The only
> difference between them is whether you’re in a downtrend or uptrend.
>
> - An Inverted Hammer is a bullish reversal candlestick.
> - A Shooting Star is a bearish reversal candlestick.

[image]

Tradingview has a built-in indicator for that as well.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Shooting Star - Bearish", shorttitle = "Shooting Star - Bear", overlay=true)

C_DownTrend = true
C_UpTrend = true
var trendRule1 = "SMA50"
var trendRule2 = "SMA50, SMA200"
var trendRule = input.string(trendRule1, "Detect Trend Based On", options=[trendRule1, trendRule2, "No detection"])

if trendRule == trendRule1
    priceAvg = ta.sma(close, 50)
    C_DownTrend := close < priceAvg
    C_UpTrend := close > priceAvg

if trendRule == trendRule2
    sma200 = ta.sma(close, 200)
    sma50 = ta.sma(close, 50)
    C_DownTrend := close < sma50 and sma50 < sma200
    C_UpTrend := close > sma50 and sma50 > sma200
C_Len = 14 // ta.ema depth for bodyAvg
C_ShadowPercent = 5.0 // size of shadows
C_ShadowEqualsPercent = 100.0
C_DojiBodyPercent = 5.0
C_Factor = 2.0 // shows the number of times the shadow dominates the candlestick body

C_BodyHi = math.max(close, open)
C_BodyLo = math.min(close, open)
C_Body = C_BodyHi - C_BodyLo
C_BodyAvg = ta.ema(C_Body, C_Len)
C_SmallBody = C_Body < C_BodyAvg
C_LongBody = C_Body > C_BodyAvg
C_UpShadow = high - C_BodyHi
C_DnShadow = C_BodyLo - low
C_HasUpShadow = C_UpShadow > C_ShadowPercent / 100 * C_Body
C_HasDnShadow = C_DnShadow > C_ShadowPercent / 100 * C_Body
C_WhiteBody = open < close
C_BlackBody = open > close
C_Range = high-low
C_IsInsideBar = C_BodyHi[1] > C_BodyHi and C_BodyLo[1] < C_BodyLo
C_BodyMiddle = C_Body / 2 + C_BodyLo
C_ShadowEquals = C_UpShadow == C_DnShadow or (math.abs(C_UpShadow - C_DnShadow) / C_DnShadow * 100) < C_ShadowEqualsPercent and (math.abs(C_DnShadow - C_UpShadow) / C_UpShadow * 100) < C_ShadowEqualsPercent
C_IsDojiBody = C_Range > 0 and C_Body <= C_Range * C_DojiBodyPercent / 100
C_Doji = C_IsDojiBody and C_ShadowEquals

patternLabelPosLow = low - (ta.atr(30) * 0.6)
patternLabelPosHigh = high + (ta.atr(30) * 0.6)

label_color_bearish = input(color.red, "Label Color Bearish")
C_ShootingStarBearishNumberOfCandles = 1
C_ShootingStarBearish = false
if C_SmallBody and C_Body > 0 and C_BodyHi < hl2 and C_UpShadow >= C_Factor * C_Body and not C_HasDnShadow
    if C_UpTrend
        C_ShootingStarBearish := true
alertcondition(C_ShootingStarBearish, title = "New pattern detected", message = "New Shooting Star – Bearish pattern detected")
if C_ShootingStarBearish
    var ttBearishShootingStar = "Shooting Star\nThis single day pattern can appear during an uptrend and opens high, while it closes near its open. It trades much higher as well. It is bearish in nature, but looks like an Inverted Hammer."
    label.new(bar_index, patternLabelPosHigh, text="SS", style=label.style_label_down, color = label_color_bearish, textcolor=color.white, tooltip = ttBearishShootingStar)
bgcolor(ta.highest(C_ShootingStarBearish?1:0, C_ShootingStarBearishNumberOfCandles)!=0 ? color.new(color.red, 90) : na, offset=-(C_ShootingStarBearishNumberOfCandles-1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! *Hanging Man Pattern* also looks similar?

Comment: Yes, it is also a single candlestick reversal pattern. Only difference is, where the body forms.